# Prove there is only finitely many Fourier coefficients of f that are non-zero

Tags: fourier-transform

[image]

Can you give me a proof of this?

Comment: What have you tried?  If it is true it must hinge on smooth because a triangle wave has infinitely many nonzero coefficients.

Comment: I don't know what does f contained in [a, b] mean, since f is a 2$\pi$ periodic function.

Comment: It means $f$ is nonzero in $[a,b]$ which is a subset of $[0, 2\pi]$, then $f$ is periodic outside $[0, 2\pi]$

Comment: The definition of the support of $f$ is not correct : it's  not $[a,b]$ but $[a,b]+2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ (the support of $f$ is the smallest closed set that contains the values of $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way: $f$ being a finite Fourier sum is analytic. But an analytic function on ${\mathbb R}$ can only have isolated zeros.

Comment: Can you tell me why f being a finite Fourier Sum is analytic? And I also don't understand why analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}$only have isolated zeros.

Comment: A function $f$ on ${\Bbb R}$ is analytic if at every point $a\in {\Bbb R}$, $f$   has a Taylor-series of positive radius of convergence $R>0$ and equals its Taylor-series: $f(a+t)= \sum_{k\geq 0} c_k t^k$  for $|t|<R$. This is the case for any $b_n e^{inx}$ ($R=+\infty$), whence a finite sum of such terms. If this $f$ has a zero at $a$, then in a neighborhood, $f(a+t)=\sum_{k\geq 1} c_k t^k$ (the term $c_0=0$ by hypothesis). If $f$ is not identically zero, there is a smallest non-vanishing $c_{m}$, $m\geq 1$ and $f(a+t)=t^m (c_m + O(t))$ is non-zero for $t$ ($\neq 0$) small enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have noticed that by using identity theorem, we can get $f(z)$ must be equal to zero in $\mathbb{R}$, which contradicts the problem itself.

Comment: Indeed you need to go from the local argument to a global one: Suppose $f$ is analytic and vanishes on some non-empty interval $I$ and let $a=\inf I < b=\sup I$. If $a>-\infty$ then the previous argument shows that $f$ must vanish in a neighborhood of $a$ contradicting the definition of $a$. Similarly for $b$. Thus, $I={\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Your argument is perfect! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f$ is the sum of its Fourier series, and therefore if there are only finitely many nonzero coefficients it is a trigonometric polynomial.  Trigonometric polynomials are rational functions in $e^{ix}$ and therefore ...